# html aligning element : html paragraph, attribute or css?

Tags: html, css, optimization, styles

In html (specific browsers), some elements CANNOT be aligned using the attribute "align=middle" directly.
    Therefore, i sometimes use `<p align="middle"><!--some elements--></p>` to align a element.
    Is this good? Is there other method, e.g. using css, to align element, would be better?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: the attribute `align` is not supported in HTML5, You should use css

Comment: oh, i see. p align is still working fine, but css `float`? i can't find a solution to float the element to the middle. pls help a bit, pls pls.

Comment: ok, to center block elements with css: `.center{margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;width:80%;}` width cannot be 100%

Comment: that's much better, but still thanks! already very good, but is still looking forward to better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a, p and div tags best solution would be CSS align|pos(center, left, right...);
As Frankenscarf's reply;
    ...

Divs;

```
<div align="center">....</div>
```

For forms you should use margin. Using margin to put something in the middle requires a width.
Example: (Would recommend percentages for responsiveness)

```
width: 500px
margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
```

Answer (score 1):

It's best to use CSS, like this:

```
<p style="text-align:center">...</p>
```

The "align" attribute for elements like `<p>` is no longer supported in HTML5.

Comment: what about some form & div elements? i tried aligning them using p style but it didn't really aligned to EXACTLY middle. (or it should be some elements else, i really have forgot it, don't ask me about that. i will forget everything else and if you later ask me, i will reply you `javascript:void(0)`.)

Comment: See [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/34xkW/) for 3 examples; p, div, and a text input field. The align attribute for div is no longer supported in HTML5 either.

Comment: Three of them in fiddle are all aligned middle